# how to calculate percentage in a group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, percentage

I have a problem with percentage of subtotal in SSRS:
My data is as below:

[image]

I want to calculate percentage of branch amount for every customer.
Could anybody please help me out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a row group in your report that groups on Customer and also assuming this row group is called `rgCustomer` then you should be able to do something like.

```
=SUM(Fields.Amount.Value)/SUM(Fields.Amount.Value, "rgCustomer")
```

You can then format the textbox as something like `p0` to show as a percentage with 0 decimal places.

**Notes:**

1. The `"rgCustomer"` part neds to be swapped out for the name of the rowgroup that groups by customer.
2. It must be enclosed in quotes
3. It is case sensitive
4. This does not take into account if you have zero values displayed
   then potentially you could have a zero customer total which would
   give a divide by 0 error (this may not be an issue in your case
   though)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

It helped.
But i have replaced "rgCustomer" with "rgBranch",becouse I wanted to calculate customer amount in his own branch.As below:
SUM(Fields.Amount.Value)/SUM(Fields.Amount.Value, "rgCustomer")